# Postman Get Request Set Environment Variable

Tags: json, postman

I have a `GET` request in Postman. I am trying to set an Environment Variable for `objectId` from the response body.

Here is my response body which is fine.

```
{

  "odata.metadata": "https://graph.windows.net/myorganization/$metadata#directoryObjects/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User",

    "value": [

    {

        "odata.type": "Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User",

        "objectType": "User",

        "objectId": "0fjrkfkfc-50b1-4259-a778-sjvmfgr5bhjj",          
   }
        ]
}
```

I have tried the following to save the objectId as an Environment Variable but its not working.  Any help will be appreciated.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("testtoken", jsonData.value[1]);  // returns [object Object]
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("testtoken", jsonData.odata.metadata); // returns [object Object]
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("testtoken", jsonData.value);  // returns [object Object],[object Object],[object Object], etc.
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("testtoken", jsonData.odata.metadata.value);  // returns nothing
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("testtoken", jsonData.odata.metadata.value.objectId);  // returns nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost got it :)

`jsonData.value[1].objectId` should work.

`jsonData.value` will return an array containing single element - object with keys `odata.type`, `objectType` and `objectId`.

Comment: actually it was jsonData.value[1].objectId